# Need to restrict screen's width but keep the whole screen scrollable in flutter web app

Tags: flutter

I'm making a flutter web application and want to restrict screen's width but at the same time keep the whole screen scrollable like it's done in twitter website.
[image: twitter has whole page scrollable]

I use primary Scaffold to determine whether to show bottomAppBar or navigation rail. Inside body of that Scaffold I put inner Scaffolds wrapped iniside ContrainedBox(maxWidth: 650) so I restrict the width of the content. The problem is that scroll bar is attached to inner Scaffolds but not to the screen. Below is the minimum representation code.

```
class MinimalHomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const MinimalHomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) {
        final bool isMobile = constraints.maxWidth <= 600;

        return Scaffold(
          // show bottom bar if width is small
          bottomNavigationBar: isMobile
              ? BottomNavigationBar(
                  items: [
                    BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home)),
                    BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.search)),
                  ],
                )
              : null,
          // The content is centered and its maxWidth is 650
          body: Center(
            child: ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 650),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  // show navigation rail if width is not small
                  if (!isMobile)
                    NavigationRail(
                        destinations: [
                          NavigationRailDestination(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: Text('Home')),
                          NavigationRailDestination(icon: Icon(Icons.search), label: Text('Search')),
                        ],
                        selectedIndex: 0,
                    ),

                  // show content
                  Expanded(
                    child: Scaffold(
                      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Title')),
                      body: ListView.separated(
                        itemCount: 100,
                        itemBuilder: (_, __) {
                          return Container(
                            height: 50,
                            width: double.infinity,
                            color: Colors.green,
                          );
                        },
                        separatorBuilder: (_, __) {
                          return Divider();
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    );
  }
}
```

[image: flutter app has scrolling on only scrollable widgets]

I need to scroll my content from any part of screen but I don't really know how to do that. I also need to use inner scaffolds to have logic inside them like back button on AppBar.
[image: the routing logic inside content remains (back button)]

I think I have to use NestedScrollView or CustomScrollView but I didn't come up with solution after hours of attemps. I also looked into 'responsive framework' package but it also remains scrolling for only scrollable part of content but not the whole screen. If someone knows how to solve this typical issue, please, help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to listen the whole screen scrolling in web like this:

```
document.onMouseWheel.listen((event) {
  event.deltaY; // scroll offset
});
```

So we can get scroll offset, put it in some stream, get it from widget which contains ListView/GridView etc, calculate offset inside ScrollController and use jumpTo() method of ScrollController. But the problem is that the given trackpad offset from onMouseWheel is little. So after hours of trying different ways like Listener widget and some libraries I decided to stop slaming my head against the wall and redisign my application. I hope there'll come a day when such a task is solved easily

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement needs more effort in Flutter framework to achieve this. The possible solution I can think of is to separate the scroll part and the Appbar/NavigationRail part apart by using Stack.

Here is my workaround: (I only handle the `!mobile` Layout)

```
BottomNavigationBar bottomNavigationBar() {
  return BottomNavigationBar(
    items: const [
      BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: ''),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.search), label: ''),
    ],
  );
}

NavigationRail navigationRail() {
  return NavigationRail(
    destinations: const [
      NavigationRailDestination(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: Text('Home')),
      NavigationRailDestination(
          icon: Icon(Icons.search), label: Text('Search')),
    ],
    selectedIndex: 0,
  );
}

class MinimalHomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const MinimalHomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        children: [
          Positioned.fill(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Center(
                child: ConstrainedBox(
                  constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 650),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 72),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: [
                        const SizedBox(height: 50),
                        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) ...[
                          Container(
                            height: 50,
                            width: double.infinity,
                            color: Colors.green,
                          ),
                          const Divider()
                        ]
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: 0,
            bottom: 0,
            width: 650,
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                navigationRail(),
                Expanded(
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 56,
                    child: AppBar(
                      title: const Text('Title'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```